# CSS - How to avoid element content to be displayed on 2 lines

Tags: css

i have a lot of span displayed inline. My spans contain some text. My problem is that when a span reaches the right border of the browser, the span is "cut". By cut I mean half is on one line the rest on the next line. I would like to avoid that. If not enough space to display all the span content on the same line, I would like that span content to be displayed on the next line. Hope I am clear. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

http://jsfiddle.net/EaW5t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS:

```
 span { white-space:nowrap; }
```

From [the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop):

> nowrap - This value collapses white space as for 'normal', but suppresses line breaks within text.

Cheers

Comment: You're welcome, if you feel I answered your question, I'd appreciate it if you'd accept it as the correct answer.  :)